# The number $m+n^2$ is divisible by $m+n$. Prove that the number $m+n^3$ is divisible by $m+n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility

> $m$ and $n$ are positive integer numbers; $m+n\mid m+n^2$.
>   Prove that $m+n\mid m+n^3$

So far I have done:

If $m+n\mid m+n^2$, then $m+n\mid (m+n^2)-(m+n)=n^2-n=n(n-1)$.

$m+n^3=n(n^2-n)+(m+n^2)$ and each component is divisible by $m+n$

Proved, thanks for help!

Comment: Maybe a hind could be that we can write $(m+n)k = m+n^2, k \in \mathbb Z$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: If $m + n^2$ is divisible by $m + n$ then so is $(m + n^2) - (m + n) = n^2 - n$.

Comment: @Natalia What I suggest to you is to spend an hour or two working on this. Then edit your question to show what attempts you've made. If you do this it is possible your question can be reopened.

Comment: Edited, almost there :)

Comment: Sorry but I figured it out! because m+n^3=n(n^2-n)+(m+n^2), thanks!